# How to clone a specific version of a git repository?

Tags: git, symfony

I'm working with symfony2 and I want to backup my vendors in case github is not reachable.

How do I clone a specific Version of a repository?

I want to backup the repositories with help of the vendors-file.

the syntax is something like this:

```
[symfony]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=v2.0.9
```

now how do I tell git to get that specific version? Is there a terminal-command like:

```
git clone --mirror http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git --version=v2.0.9
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: When you clone a git repository you get a copy of the whole project. You can checkout any tag/branch from your local copy. See http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#how-to-check-out

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What I would do to tell git to use this exact version is:

```
git clone http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
cd symfony

git checkout v2.0.9
```

One liner:

```
git clone http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git -b v2.0.9
```

Answer (score 3):

The following might get you there:

```
git clone --branch <branch> <repo>
```

If you are looking for a specific version, then first create a branch off that version from your working repository.  Like such:

```
# In a local, working repository
git checkout -b v2.0.9-br v2.0.9
git push origin

# Now create your clone from v2.0.9-br
```

Note, I've assumed v2.0.9 is a version (tag), not a branch.  If it is a branch, then just clone with the '--branch' option.

Answer (score 1):

You can't clone a repository specifying only a version number. You also can't clone a repository by specifying only a commit hash. (which is pretty much the same thing from Git's point of view)

Actually the only thing you can do is a shallow clone by specifying the depth (the number of commits you will pull): http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-clone

`git clone --depth 1` would pull only the last commit.

Back to your question, if you fear that github is unreachable, you should host these projects on one of your server.