# Removing all commit after a specific one? Or cloning at a specific commit

Tags: git, github

If I download something from Github, and I want to locally wipe out everything that occurred after a given commit, how can I do this?

Or conversely, is it possible for me to download/clone a repository at a certain point in time? (it will be a few months old, but I don't want any of the changes after a specific point to show up in my repository at all)

I know the commit, say it is `abc123def`.

Comment: You might not have found this because your wording is a bit different, but your question is essentially a dup, and [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303665/how-to-clone-a-specific-version-of-a-git-repository) :)

Answer (score 0):

When you clone a repository in Git you can't select a specific revision. You need to clone the entire repository.

If you want to wipe out all the changes from HEAD to one specific revision, you can count the number of commit between that revision and head

```
$ git log --oneline abc123def..HEAD | wc -l
```

Then run reset passing the number of commits you want to remove (eg. 123)

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~123
```

Comment: Why not just use `checkout` (and maybe create a new branch, if new commits are to be added). hard-resetting seems a bit harsh in this case, though I guess it would still work (as presumably no new changes will be pulled in from upstream).

Comment: `checkout` will just leave him with a detached head and a situation he will have to sort out. And he clearly stated `wipe out` – harsh methods for harsh intentions :).

Answer (score 0):

Cloning a repository involves downloading all remote refs and all commits needed for them.
(At least I am not aware of a way to restrict this.)

Once you cloned the repository you are free to set up your own branches to arbitrary commits.

You probably want something like `git clone -n $url` and `git checkout -b mybranch abc123def`.

After that you should see with `git branch -av` that there is your branch pointing to your old commit as well as the remote branches pointing to the new commits.

From the point of your branch all newer commits do not exist anymore. That is most probably what you want.

If you really want to wipe out all newer commits from your repository you have to remove all newer refs (i.e. branches and tags) and use `git gc` to clean everything up.

Answer (score 0):

Simone is basically right, but there is a simpler way. First, as said a clone will always clone everything and you can’t help that. But thanks to git’s extreme speed that’s usually not a problem. After the clone, simply check out your branch and run:

```
git reset --hard abc123def
```

*question for the SE pros: should this rather have been an edit to Simone’s answer?*