# OCaml - how to create queue

Tags: queue, ocaml

I want to use Queue Module, and I don;t know how to create queue for int. Only thing that I need is how to parametrize a functor.

Could you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing all commit after a specific one? Or cloning at a specific commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013446/removing-all-commit-after-a-specific-one-or-cloning-at-a-specific-commit)

Answer (score 4):

The standard Queue module is not a functor. Moreover, it provides imperative-style queues. In other words, the standard enqueue/dequeue operations mutate the state of the queue. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# let myq = Queue.create ();;
val myq : '_a Queue.t = <abstr>
# Queue.add 4 myq;;
- : unit = ()
# Queue.add 100 myq;;
- : unit = ()
# Queue.take myq;;
- : int = 4
# Queue.take myq;;
- : int = 100
#
```